# Is there a PHP/Composer tool which works like npm version?

Tags: php, git, composer-php

Is there an automated way of updating the version number in composer.json and adding the necessary tags before publishing, like the way `npm version` does?

I mean, if you had a composer.json with the line `"version": "2.1.3"`, and executed:

```
composer version minor
```

It would do the following:

- Updating the version number in `composer.json` to `2.2.0`
- Triggering `composer update` to update `composer.lock`
- Making a new `git commit`
- Making a new git tag `v2.2.0`

I know that the `composer version` command doesn't exist, but is there an equivalent tool?

Comment: No but you could put in a feature request: https://github.com/composer/composer

Comment: Thanks, @PaulCrovella this was also a valuable feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`npm version` does stuff that you very likely do not need for Composer:

- The version number is not recorded in `composer.json` if there are other means available - and because you are referring to Git later on, they are available.
- Updating dependencies in the lock file is unnecessary. The lock file will be ignored when the project you are dealing with is included somewhere else.
- Because nothing has changed in the project, a `git commit` wouldn't do anything.
- All this leaves you with creating a new tag in the Git repository. Putting this into Composer would mean you'd exchange one command with another, without any big benefit besides you won't have to lookup the current version number you are dealing with if you use some of the relative `version` parameters.

All in all I'd say that simply tagging your new version is enough for Composer. You'd probably need to have some infrastructure in place and configured to make the world aware of the new version:

- If your package is open source and on packagist.org, you should have a post-commit hook to notify them as soon as a new version is available. This is a standard option on Github, I don't know about other source code hosts.
- Otherwise if you have to feed closed source code, you'd probably start a new update cycle of whatever system is used to create an alternative package information source (be it Satis, locally hosted Packagist, Toran Proxy or Private Packagist)

This however depends on how you set up things.

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason and despite all voices against it you still want to use a tool like the OP asked for, https://www.npmjs.com/package/composer-version works quite well.